# Group by NOT having element in common?

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, sorting, group-by

I have a class such as:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public HashSet<int> Items;
}
```

I want to group SomeClass with other SomeClass that DON'T share any Items in common.
Example: Assume we have 3 SomeClass (S1-S4) such as:
S1:
• Items: 1, 2, 6
S2:
• Items: 3, 4, 5
S3:
• Items: 1
S4:
• Items: 1, 5
S5:
• Items: 8, 9

In that case, the groups should be as follows:
G1: S1, S2, S5
G2: S3
G3: S4

Ideally, items should be placed in the group with the least members so all groups can be relatively the same size.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: How is `S1-S4` out of S1 to S5 `3 SomeClass`?

Comment: Why not G2: S3, S2, S5; G3: S4, S5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to define this grouping in Linq. `GroupBy` in Linq requires a definition of "equality", and that definition must be transitive, meaning that if `A=B` and `B=C`, then `A=C` must be true.  Your definition is not transitive, as in your inputs, `S1=S2`, and `S2=S3`, but `S1!=S3`.

What you *could* do is loop through all items, creating new groups as needed, and adding items to groups to keep the sizes low as you state.

So you could start with `S1`, look for other items that contain `1`, and put them in new groups (`S3` and `S4` in this case). Then look for items that contain `2` put them in the groups created in step 1, alternating groups.

By that logic you should end up with:

```
G1: S1, S2
G2: S3, S5
G3: S4
```

But, again, that can't be done in Linq - you'll have to code the loop and grouping logic yourself.

Comment: If you consider "Aggregate" as LINQ it can be done with it... (code shown in my entertainment-purposes-only answer)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is strictly for entertainment purposes, provides a single statement conversion that may be even considered LINQ you count "Aggregate" as LINQ (LINQPad-ready):

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new[] {
        new SomeClass("s1", 1,2,6),
        new SomeClass("s2", 3,4,5), 
        new SomeClass("s3", 1),
        new SomeClass("s4", 1,5), 
        new SomeClass ("s5", 8,9)
    };
    
    var r = list.Aggregate(new List<IEnumerable<SomeClass>>().AsEnumerable(),
        (result, cur) => result
            // groups that should be copied
            .Where(w => w != result.FirstOrDefault(
                  x => x.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Intersect(cur.Items).Count() == 0))
            .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(
                // adding to existing one
                (result.FirstOrDefault(
                   x => x.SelectMany(c => c.Items).Intersect(cur.Items).Count() == 0) ??
                // adding to new one
                new List<SomeClass>())
                    // add current item to existing/new group
                    .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(cur, 1)),
                1))
            );
                                 
    r.Dump();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass(string name, params int[] items)
    {
        Name = name;
        Items= new HashSet<int>(items);
    }
    public string Name;
    public HashSet<int> Items;
}
```

Sort-of explanation:

on every iteration

- split list of groups into two half - first suitable group to add current item and the rest using the same condition.
- for groups in the rest (`.Where` selects all but the potential first suitable group) just let them move to next iteration untouched
- for the suitable group there are two options - we actually have a group to add to or there is no such group and we need to create new one. To unify code we just use `result.FirstOrDefault(...) ?? new List<...>()` - this gives a list to add new item which is either have items from previous iterations or new one.
- add current item to the suitable group - `.Concat` requires IEnumerable which we construct with `Enumerable.Repeat(cur,1)`.
- concatenate "list of groups to copy" with "list of single group with current element".

Notes if you try to hack up the same code yourself:

- it is very easy to add "current" group to multiple existing groups if you just check "no intersection". We must only consider first suitable group to get code working correctly
- subsequently it is easy to lose existing if you try to use some sort of "intersects" filter that doesn't stop on first match.
- Think about top level `Concat` as "split list into two parts based on true/false" and merge modified results.
- Creating new group is easy to get wrong/miss altogether.